# How are Ley Lines created in The Hollows

Tags: the-hollows

In The Hollows series by Kim Harrison, Ley Lines are the source of magic and are connected to Demons. While I thought I'd read the whole series, in later books Rachel

> Refers to a Ley Line as "hers" and the text implied that she had created it. This was in someway related to her Rosewood Syndrome, which meant she was a "real" Demon.

But I don't recall this event happening, can anyone explain how the Lines are created, or point me at the relevant sections of the books?

Comment: Agh, I know there is a scene with Rachel where she does something while in the ever-after with Al to create a ley line...later in the series IIRC. I'll have to look through the books to find it though.

Comment: I've found passages where they talk about the ley line she created, haven't narrowed it down to the creation though. Still looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Rachel created a ley line accidentally in [The Magic Sanction](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6547188-black-magic-sanction) (Book 8) when she attempted to jump by herself, using an untrained gargoyle, to warn to the coven against summoning Al. The ley line is physically located at Loveland Castle. It arises as a plot point in later books, notably in [Ever After](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13241659-ever-after) (Book 11) when

> the demon Ku'Soc deliberately damages the line, causing magic to drain from Ever After, and places the blame for this on Rachel

As to what exactly a ley line is, Harrison gave a nice description in an interview for [Lightspeed magazine](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/nonfiction/feature-interview-kim-harrison/):

> The magic is run in my universe by ley lines—the idea of ley lines has
> been around for a long time. Not really popular until the last ten
> years or so. I take that, which is mythical, but then I go in and say,
> “Well, maybe it’s a rift in time where the energy is leaking through
> or maybe it’s the back end of a wormhole.” So I try to find a basis
> for it. It turns out **they are a kind of slice in the fabric of time
> where you can get to an alternate reality where the demons have been**

Further details were given in *The Magic Sanction*. The ley lines were made by the demons during the demon-elf wars:

> Upon banishing the elves, they flung themselves back to reality, their
> tracks scarring time and making ley lines."
>
> "Demons made the ley lines?" I interrupted, surprised, and he nodded.

These lines, arising from jumps from reality to Ever After are permanent.
The line that Rachel made accidentally, however, arose from a reality-to-reality jump ("dragging her sorry existence a full twenty feet as the Earth turned under her"), and so was inherently unstable. For this reason it was theorised in *Ever After* that killing Rachel would eliminate the line, and the problems it was causing.